# Is socket.write thread" safe?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am using node.js to communicate over a socket in json. One of the operations sends a big file over the socket in base64 format. As a result the message is split into packets and triggers various data events on the client. I handle this using a buffer on the client side

```
var response={
    file: fs.readFileSync("FileName","base64")
}
socket.write(JSON.stringify(response));
```

On the client side, using a buffer

```
cleartextStream.on("data",function(data){
            console.log("Received data")

            try {

                data=JSON.parse(data);
                _buffer="";
                events.trigger(data.event,data);
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log("Incomplete message received. Building Buffer");
                _buffer+=data;
                if(/\}$/.test(data) ){//Tests for json boundary
                    data=JSON.parse(_buffer);
                    events.trigger(data.event,data);

                }
            }
```

This works fine for me for now. The only problem I anticipate is if while the file is being sent, some other event triggers a write on the socket.

```
t=0 Start sending file
t=5 Still sending file
t=6 Another event uses socket.write to start sending message
t=7 still sending file
t=8 Another event sending message
```

This will result in garbled messages. So does socket.write block while sending a single message, or will it allow other methods to use socket.write even before the transmission is completed?